# Problem to install Acr UserDialogs in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin

Regards my coledges, I am new to programing in xamarin forms with visual studio 2019, and I want to install the nuget package AcrUser Dialogs and give me error:

NU1202: Package Acr.UserDialogs 8.0.1 is not compatible with xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0). Package Acr.UserDialogs 8.0.1 supports:

- net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0)
- net6.0-android31.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0)
- net6.0-ios15.4 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0)
- net6.0-maccatalyst15.4 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0)

reinstall the package not resolve the problem, Help coledges

Comment: use an older version of the package, or upgrade your project to use a current version of Xamarin

Answer (score 0):

Read the error message: it's not compatible with your project's target.

Look at the project's supported platform list: https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs?tab=readme-ov-file#support-platforms.

> v7.x Supports
>
> iOS 8+ Android,
> Universal Windows Platform (Win10/UWP),
> NET Standard 2.0
>
> v8.x Supports ONLY .NET 6 target
>
> .NET for Android (major target 12), .NET for iOS, .NET for MacCatalyst

To use this project in Xamarin you have to install v7 and earlier.